# PYGTK Handle Keypress in popup window

Tags: python, pygtk, keypress

Basically I have some code that creates three popup windows. I would like to be able to handle keypresses even though there are no actual toplevel windows. I create the popup windows like so:

```
self.window1 = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)
```

Comment: You can simply do `self.window1.connect("key-press-event", your_function)` or `widget.connect("key-press-event", func)` with `self.window1.add(widget)`. If this is not what you meant, you should clarify your question and provide a working, minimal example.

Comment: From my testing, I've noticed that WINDOW_POPUP type windows don't catch key press events with `self.window.connect("key-press-event")`. This is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Using a POPUP window is generally a bad idea unless you are creating something complex by scratch, this type of windows are not controlled by the WM. If you need a window with no decoration just do set_decorated(False)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: You could use the keybinder module, bind the keys as the window realize and unbind them as soon as they unrealize or you performed the operation. Remember that keybinder catches every key pressed system wide, so it's better to avoid normal keys (eg. letters and numbers) without modifiers, if you really don't need to.